# Plant identification - what plant is this?

Tags: identification

A neighbor left their plants in the hallway with a sign of “please take me” when they moved out. I took this one because I like it, but I’m not sure how much sun or water needs and I don’t have my ex neighbor contact. Could you please help me to identify the plant? :)
[image]

Comment: Some kind of philodendron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Colocasia (Elephant Ear) plant. It is in the Araceae family, which has more well known family members such as Philodendrons, Dieffenbachia (also known as 'Dumb Cane') and Pothos.

Like their more well known cousins, Elephant Ear plants need lots of indirect sunlight and a moderately moist soil. The general rule is to allow the top 1-2 inches of soil to dry between watering.

I have grown Elephant Ear plants both in shady parts of the garden and as houseplants.